# Combine duplicates but not all of them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` as the one below. I want to combine the duplicates in the `'activity'` column except from the ones called `'selection'`, and sum their value in the `'duration'` column. I am doing it in R. I've tried using `aggregate()` but I couldn't find the way to not aggregate the `'selection'` rows.

```
 # df - I used dput so you can have my df
test <- structure(list(activity = c("selection", "selection", "selection", 
"other", "inspection", "assignment", "inspection", "inspection", 
"inspection", "inspection"), workers = c("worker 1", "worker 1", 
"worker 1", "worker 34", "worker 6", "worker 5", "worker 2", 
"worker 2", "worker 2", "worker 2"), start_time = structure(c(1645396200, 
1645396200, 1645396200, 1645394352, 1645394155, 1645394100, 1645390080, 
1645476480, 1645562880, 1645649280), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), status = c("passed", "passed", "passed", "passed", 
"passed", "passed", "passed", "passed", "passed", "passed"), 
    duration = c(8.98333333333333, 9.69027777777778, 9.20555555555556, 
    0.557222222222222, 2.24527777777778, 1.61666666666667, 2.12166666666667, 
    1.32638888888889, 2.59861111111111, 0.765555555555556)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  
test 
# A tibble: 10 x 5
       activity   workers   start_time          status duration
       <chr>      <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>     <dbl>
     1 selection  worker 1  2022-02-20 22:30:00 passed    8.98 
     2 selection  worker 1  2022-02-20 22:30:00 passed    9.69 
     3 selection  worker 1  2022-02-20 22:30:00 passed    9.21 
     4 other      worker 34 2022-02-20 21:59:12 passed    0.557
     5 inspection worker 6  2022-02-20 21:55:55 passed    2.25 
     6 assignment worker 5  2022-02-20 21:55:00 passed    1.62 
     7 inspection worker 2  2022-02-20 20:48:00 passed    2.12 
     8 inspection worker 2  2022-02-21 20:48:00 passed    1.33 
     9 inspection worker 2  2022-02-22 20:48:00 passed    2.60 
    10 inspection worker 2  2022-02-23 20:48:00 passed    0.766
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post data as images. We don't want to have to retype everything just to try out possible solutions. Please share your code attempt as well. Exactly what duplicates would be eliminated here? It seems all the duration values are unique. Please give the expected output for this sample input.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the quick reply. The df is just a small part of my real df. So, I have to combine all the duplicates (and sum the duration) except for the ones called 'selection'. The selection duplicates should remain the same. Thanks for the 'reproducible example' link. It helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to fully understand what you are looking for but I give it a try!

So, using the `dplyr` library, you could do:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  filter(activity != "selection") %>% 
  group_by(activity) %>% 
  summarise(workers = workers[1],
            start_time = start_time[1],
            status = status[1],
            duration = sum(duration)) %>% 
  bind_rows(test %>% filter(activity == "selection"))
```

- Output

```
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   activity   workers   start_time          status duration
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 assignment worker 5  2022-02-20 21:55:00 passed    1.62 
#> 2 inspection worker 6  2022-02-20 21:55:55 passed    9.06 
#> 3 other      worker 34 2022-02-20 21:59:12 passed    0.557
#> 4 selection  worker 1  2022-02-20 22:30:00 passed    8.98 
#> 5 selection  worker 1  2022-02-20 22:30:00 passed    9.69 
#> 6 selection  worker 1  2022-02-20 22:30:00 passed    9.21
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>